# Show using centers of mass that the angle bisectors of ΔABC are concurrent at I, where I lies on bisector AP at a position such that:AI/AP = b+c/a+b+c

Tags: euclidean-geometry, physics

[image]

I found it quite easy to show that AP = a+b+c, because if b and c are the mass of points B and C respectively, P is the sum of their masses (b+c). Then segement AP has a mass of a+b+c because it includes point A with a mass of a, and point P with mass b+c. Unless that is completely off.

I'm having a difficult time trying to determine how AI=b+c.

Keep in mind, point I should be 2/3 of the distance on AP.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that if $b,c$ are masses at $B,C$ then the mass of $P$ is $b+c$. This is not necessarily true because $P$ will not necessarily be the "balance", the center of mass, between $B$ and $C$. For example, if $b=c$, then their center of mass is in the middle between them, which is *not* where $P$ is $(AP$ is an angle bisector, not a median!$)$.

To solve this right, you need to put masses in vertices $A,B,C$ in a clever way. The idea is that for example the balance between $B$ and $C$ $($the center of mass of just these two$)$ should be exactly at $P$. If that is true, this immediately tells you that the center of mass of all three points lies somewhere on the bisector $AP$, because you can find it by first finding that of $B,C$, and then adding $A$. Once you know that, it follows that the angle bisectors must intersect at one point $I$, because the center of mass of all three vertices has to lie *somewhere*, and it has to lie on every bisector.

Now, since you want the center of mass of just $B,C$ to lie at $P$, the lengths $BP$, $CP$ must be inversely proportional to the masses $B$, $C$ $($the law of the lever!$)$. But the lengths $BP$, $CP$ are themselves proportional to $AB$, $AC$, because $AP$ is the bisector $($this is a [basic property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_bisector_theorem) of angle bisectors in a triangle$)$. So actually the masses at $B$, $C$ can be inversely proportional to lengths $AB$, $AC$ respectively. For example, if $AB$ is $3$ times longer than $AC$, the mass at $B$ should be $3$ times smaller than $C$. This may give you an idea of how to select the masses for all three vertices.